# Print true values separately

Tags: python

```
a = 'abcdef'  ,'ijklmno' , 'pqrst'
b = 'ijklmno' , 'zxy'
c = b in a
print c
```

output :

```
 True , False
```

How to print the value of true separately . i'e 'ijklmno' is true so i want to print it seperately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression of the form `x in y` evaluates to `True` or `False` so that's what you'll get. If you want to see the common elements, do this instead.

```
a = 'abcdef'  ,'ijklmno' , 'pqrst'
b = 'ijklmno' , 'zxy'
set(a).intersection(set(b))
```

This will return `set(['ijklmno'])`.

Comment: ``set(a).intersection(b)`` works too

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output you can do this:

```
a = 'abcdef'  ,'ijklmno' , 'pqrst'
b = 'ijklmno' , 'zxy'
print [elem in a for elem in b]
```

This will return `[True, False]`.